# What modern C++ Unit Testing Framework do you use for highly parallel image, 3D and higher dimensional matrix processing workloads?

Tags: 3d, image-processing, c++, gpu, real-time

Most of the existing open-source libraries such as OpenCV, Tensorflow, and Pytorch use **Google Test**. I would like to know about strong alternative testing frameworks that thrive under a similar workload. Suggestions from areas such as real-time graphics and physics engines are absolutely welcome!

Comment: Seems to be a general coding question - not 3D graphics.  Perhaps just stackoverflow?